# Logging in with Discord OAuth2 using Nuxt's auth-module

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, nuxt.js

I am having a hard time setting up a login method using [Discord's OAuth2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) and [Nuxt's auth-module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) below is my setup and currently, the way it works is I go to `https://website.com/login` which redirects me to Discord's OAuth2 authorisation page and when I authorise it, I get redirected to `https://website.com/token?code=CODE&state=STATE`, I then exchange the `code` for an `access_token` and a `refresh_token`, this is where I am stuck, I have tried to set the user using `context.$auth.setUser({ AccessToken: res.data.access_token })` which is also supposed to set the user's `loggedIn` status to `true` but that is reverted once I refresh the page.

What do I do once I get the user's `access_token`?

**nuxt.config.js - auth-module config**

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    discord: {
      _scheme: 'oauth2',
      authorization_endpoint: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize',
      userinfo_endpoint: false,
      scope: ['email', 'identify', 'connections'],
      response_type: 'code',
      redirect_uri: 'https://website.com/token',
      client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    },
  },
},
```

**/login**

```js
<script>
export default {
  middleware(context) {
    if (context.$auth.loggedIn) context.redirect('/')
  },
  created() {
    if (process.client) this.$auth.loginWith('discord')
  },
}
</script>
```

**/token**

```js
<script>
const formUrlEncode = (data) => {
  return Object.entries(data)
    .map(([k, v]) => k + '=' + v)
    .join('&')
}
export default {
  async asyncData(context) {
    const data = {
      client_id: context.env.CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: context.$config.CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: context.query.code,
      redirect_uri: 'https://website.com/token',
      scope: 'identify email connections',
    }

    const res = await context.$axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token',
      data: formUrlEncode(data),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @Syntle, any chance you found a solution yourself? I've got more or less the same struggle atm.